# Почему вызов WinAPI-функции выбрасывает AccessViolationException?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int SetEntriesInAcl(
    int cCountOfExplicitEntries,
    ref EXPLICIT_ACCESS pListOfExplicitEntries,
    IntPtr OldAcl,
    out IntPtr NewAcl);

private void SomeMethod()
{
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS explicit_access = new EXPLICIT_ACCESS();

    // заполнение структуры explicit_access  значениями

    IntPtr pDACL = IntPtr.Zero;
    SetEntriesInAcl(1, ref explicit_access, IntPtr.Zero, out pDACL);
}
```

При вызове функции SetEntriesInAcl вылетает `AccessViolationException: attempted to read or write protected memory`. Изолировала этот код и поняла, что если он выполняется под .NET 4.6.2, то нормально отрабатывает. А вот если выполняется под версией 4.0, то вылетает исключение. Поменять целевую платформу не могу. Что сделать, чтобы данная функция успешно отрабатывала в моём проекте?

Comment: Вы уверены, что дело именно в версии .NET, а не в разрядности? Начиная с 4.5 появился флаг prefer 32bit и помянялось поведение для AnyCpu, возможно дело в этом.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: вполне возможно. Размер IntPtr ведь зависит от разрядности

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Да, в этом. Поменяла target platform на x86 и нормально отработало. Но повлияет ли это как-то на выполнение моего проекта на платформах x64?

Comment: Приложения x86 запускаются на 64-битных системах, но 32-битную библиотеку нельзя загрузить в 64-битный процесс, как и наоборот. Так или иначе, лучше исправить код, так чтобы все работало независимо от разрядности. В определении функции, на первый взгляд, все в порядке, значит ошибка в объявлении структуры EXPLICIT_ACCESS.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight я использовала вот эту реализацию: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.EXPLICIT_ACCESS и реализация TRUSTEE: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/TRUSTEE.html

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight кругом используются UIntPtr, IntPtr и перечисления (enum). У меня нет предположений где может быть ошибка объявления структуры.

Comment: Поля структуры EXPLICIT_ACCESS неправильные. Они должны быть uint, а не UIntPtr

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight действительно. На msdn (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/accctrl/ns-accctrl-_explicit_access_a) у этих полей типы данных DWORD, а не LPDWORD. Не надо было доверять этому порталу (pinvoke.net), а самой всё проверять. Спасибо за помощь.